# Array initialization error in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am declaring an array "params" in a method.  It is only used in the method so this seemed appropriate.  Later I am using it in a series of IF statements. In the first statement that references the array, NetBeans is complaining that the variable "may never have been initialized".  Here is an example of the first few lines:

```
    private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String[] params;
    int count = 0;

    if (txtCoN.getText() != null){
        params[count] = "Company like " + txtCoN.getText();
        ++count;
```

I tried initializing right below the delcaration using `params[0]="";` and got the same error at the initialization.

How do I get rid of the initialization error?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `String[] params = new String[N];`. If you're not sure about its size, use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented.  It helped a lot.  I re-read the array documentation and obviously missed declaring a size.  I will look at an array list as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a couple of people have already said, use an `ArrayList`. This is how you use them.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
. . . 
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then to add stuff:

```
myList.add("this");
myList.add("is");
myList.add("a test!");
```

Then to access it:

```
myList.get(0)
myList.get(1)
myList.get(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate an array with a specified size, you cannot just add more elements like that.  You may want to use an ArrayList instead if you want something that expands to add more elements.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the array object (by using new), before actually being able to set any of its elements.

```
String[] params;
params[0]="";
```

Is not correct because params doesn't yet have an element `0`.

So declare as

```
String[] params = new String[SIZE];
```

Arrays in Java are fixed size too, so you must know their size at the time of construction.

For the cases when you don't know the number of elements you'll need, an array is not a good choice. Use some higher level container class (found in the `java.util` package).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String[] params= new String[count];
```

to create a new array, where the variable count can be changed to be the amount of items in your array.

Comment: That's a disaster recipe. `params[count]` will fail.

Comment: just used 0 as a placeholder, will change to a variable

Comment: Anyway, you should recommend using `ArrayList` in this case.

Comment: true, was going to do that but someone beat me to it